# How can I override the required error_message in django rest framework?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I want to override the `required` error message. For `blank` and `empty` I can do it in `extra_kwargs`, but for `required` it doesn't work:

```
class Meta:
    extra_kwargs = {
        'enticements_info': {'error_messages': {'required': 'Test.'}},
    }
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 4):

You can override the *required* `error_message` in this way.

```
class YourSerializer(ModelSerializer):
    my_default_errors = {
        "required": "This field is required",
        "blank": "This field should not blank",
    }

    enticements_info = serializers.CharField(
        required=True, error_messages=my_default_errors, min_length=10
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Your_Model
        fields = "enticements_info"
```